# Bugzilla installation problems on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bugzilla

I tried to install bugzilla 4.2.4 on Ubuntu.

After much effort fixed all dependencies, but when I run `./checksetup.pl`, I get

```
WARNING: We could not check the configuration of Apache. This sometimes
happens when you are not running checksetup.pl as root. To see the
problem we ran into, run: /usr/sbin/apache2 -t -D DUMP_MODULES

***********************************************************************
* OPTIONAL MODULES                                                    *
***********************************************************************
* Certain Perl modules are not required by Bugzilla, but by           *
* installing the latest version you gain access to additional         *
* features.                                                           *
*                                                                     *
* The optional modules you do not have installed are listed below,    *
* with the name of the feature they enable. Below that table are the  *
* commands to install each module.                                    *
***********************************************************************
*      MODULE NAME * ENABLES FEATURE(S)                               *
***********************************************************************
* Apache-SizeLimit * mod_perl                                         *
***********************************************************************
COMMANDS TO INSTALL OPTIONAL MODULES:

Apache-SizeLimit: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Apache2::SizeLimit


To attempt an automatic install of every required and optional module
with one command, do:

  /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl --all
```

When I tried the last command, I get

```
Checking for                 CPAN (v1.81)     ok: found v1.94 
Checking for                 YAML (any)       ok: found v0.84 
Checking for   ExtUtils-MakeMaker (v6.31)     ok: found v6.64 
Return::Value is deprecated at /home/user/Downloads/bugzilla-4.2.4/lib/Return/Value.pm line 13
    require Return/Value.pm called at /home/user/Downloads/bugzilla-4.2.4/lib/Email/Send.pm line 11
    Email::Send::BEGIN() called at /home/user/Downloads/bugzilla-4.2.4/lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
    eval {...} called at /home/user/Downloads/bugzilla-4.2.4/lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
    require Email/Send.pm called at (eval 76) line 1
    eval 'require Email::Send;' called at /home/user/Downloads/bugzilla-4.2.4/Bugzilla/Install/Requirements.pm line 668
    Bugzilla::Install::Requirements::have_vers('HASH(0x200d8c8)', 0) called at /home/user/Downloads/bugzilla-4.2.4/Bugzilla/Install/Requirements.pm line 445
    Bugzilla::Install::Requirements::_check_missing('ARRAY(0x20af3a0)', 0) called at /home/user/Downloads/bugzilla-4.2.4/Bugzilla/Install/Requirements.pm line 409
    Bugzilla::Install::Requirements::check_requirements(0) called at install-module.pl line 89
WARNING: We could not check the configuration of Apache. This sometimes
happens when you are not running checksetup.pl as root. To see the
problem we ran into, run: /usr/sbin/apache2 -t -D DUMP_MODULES

Going to read '/home/user/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 18 Feb 2013 05:53:02 GMT
Installing Apache2::SizeLimit version 0.96...
Apache2::SizeLimit is up to date (0.97).
```

When I try the url, localhost/bugzilla/ I get

```
Software error:

The ./data/params file does not exist. You probably need to run checksetup.pl. at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 337.
Compilation failed in require at /var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi line 34.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi line 34.
For help, please send mail to the webmaster (webmaster@localhost), giving this error message and the time and date of the error.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the variables that are normally contained in /etc/apache2/envvars:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

Then run this command to test:

```
/usr/sbin/apache2 -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

This should get rid of the first warning you mentioned. Run checksetup.pl again as this should generate data/params.

Comment: I have already checked the envvars file for that.When I run /usr/sbin/apache2 -t -D DUMP_MODULES I am getting
apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}.

Comment: That´s why I said to set the variables. I also got this warning, but in the end it wasn´t causing my problem (turned out to be suexec). Therefore, set the variables and see what other errors you might get.

Comment: Thanks Larsen. I tried a fresh installation. Now am facing another problem. My localconfig file is not created in bugzilla directory. This the output of ./checksetup.pl. http://pastebin.mozilla.org/2193224. Kindly help me fix this. Running /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl --all says XML twig is upto date. Kindly help me out.

Comment: No Problem Larsen. I have did a fresh installation on another system. Thanks for your help !!